# Git suddenly stopped working on production server

Tags: git, apache, repository, bitbucket

I'll try to be as clear as possible.

About 3 days ago, I was trying to do a `git pull` to the live server of my company. After a couple of minutes, the command didn't seem to do anything. What I mean by that is that once I hit Enter, the terminal just hung without displaying any output at all.

`git fetch`, `git ls-remote` have the same problem. No output, it just hangs without doing anything. What's curious is that if I type `git status` on my git repository in the server, it shows:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'
```

When I clearly have changes in the `master` branch. It seems that the problem is the same with all the other projects we have in the server and is not caused because of a particular misconfiguration in this specific one.

The server is Apache and our repositories are in Bitbucket.

I am sorry if this is not enough information for you to help me. I am pretty new at this, and I am trying to help my company as best as I can. If you need something else from me, I'll try to answer as fast as I can.

Comment: Both fetch and ls-remote have to call up some other Git, typically via an Internet connection. `git status` just looks at what's on that machine right now, without calling up any other Git. Apparently the "call someone else" step is hanging, so the next step is to investigate why your live server cannot make a phone call to the Bitbucket servers.

Comment: I will check on that, thank you.